# How to use RSpec with a Rails app in another folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

The Rails app is inside of the spec folder. The name of the app is RailsDemo.

How to configure rspec to work with it?

So far, I have:

spec_helper.rb

```
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../apps/railsdemo/config/application', __FILE__)
require_relative './apps/railsdemo/config/boot'
require 'railties'

def app
  RailsDemo
end
```

But this does not work. So, how can you configure rspec to test a Rails app inside the spec folder?

Use case: Yes, I know the spec folder is supposed to be in the app folder. The reason I have set it up like this is that I am writing a gem, and want to test against different apps. For example, a Rails app and a Rack app.

So, each app is in spec/apps. Within the specs, I want to switch between the apps.

Rails 5.

Comment: Man, I want to know a good way to do this, too. Here's a hacky way I did it: https://github.com/adsteel/composable_decorator/tree/master/spec/dummy